# Put two values in two separate fields Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, textfield

I need to be able to choose or pick an item from a list and after I choose it, the name of that item will go into one field and the corresponding weight to that item will go into another field.

I've been really stuck on this. I tired making a adapter but it wasn't working out and I'm just so lost, I don't know where to go with it.

I would really appreciate help.

If you need any code that I've done please say and I'll put it up straight away.

I don't have a database, I have a class of an array or numbers and Letter.

Thanks all!

Main.java

```
public void Chem() {

    Chemical chemical_data[] = new Chemical[]
            {
                    new Chemical("Acid", 125.33),
                    new Chemical("Blue", 145.3356),

            };

    ChemicalAdapter adapter = new ChemicalAdapter(this, R.layout.sollayout, chemical_data);

    chemname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    weightval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //ChemicalAdapter header =  new ChemicalAdapter(this, R.layout.sollayout, null);

    //weightval.addHeaderView(header);

    chemname.setAdapter(adapter);



}

public void Chemname()
{

    chemname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    AutoCompleteTextView b = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Chem();
        }
    });
}
```

Chemical.java

```
public class Chemical {
String chemicalValue;
double weight;

public Chemical(String chemicalValue, double weight) {
    this.chemicalValue = chemicalValue;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getChemicalValue() {
    return chemicalValue;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

}

ChemicalAdpater.java

```
public class ChemicalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chemical> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Chemical data[] = null;

public ChemicalAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Chemical[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChemicalHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ChemicalHolder();
        holder.chemname = (AutoCompleteTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        holder.weightval = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ChemicalHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Chemical chemical = data[position];
    holder.weightval.setText(String.valueOf(chemical.weight));
    holder.chemname.setText(chemical.chemicalValue);

    return row;
}

static class ChemicalHolder
{
    AutoCompleteTextView chemname;
    EditText weightval;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: And let us know just where you are stuck with appropriate error messages/exceptions

Comment: Added the code so far

Comment: Is Chemical.java in the same package as ChemicalAdpater.java?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the same package!  What I was getting was in the autocompletetextview when I clicked it was the name of the package ChemicalAdapter@ some numbers. I need to to be putting data into both fields